# Android WidgetProvider (Kotlin) and custom activity broadcast

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem with my widget. Actually it's working pretty well and I can send and receive broadcast from a custom activity to my AppWidgetProvider (that is also my BroadcastReceiver).

The problem is here : After a while (1 minutes approximately) the widget doesn't receive anymore the broadcasts sent from the custom activity.

Here is the onEnabled, onReceiver and onUpdate (you can see the code that launch the issued activity in onReceive method):

```
class TodoWidgetProvider() : AppWidgetProvider() {

override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
    super.onEnabled(context)

    Log.i("Debug", "onEnabled has been called")
    try {

        val filter = IntentFilter(StaticVariables.ACTION_NEWTASK)
        context?.applicationContext?.registerReceiver(this, filter)

        // Récupère les informations à partir du manager
        val manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        val ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context?.applicationContext?.packageName, javaClass.name))

        // Lance la mise à jour
        onUpdate(context, manager, ids)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Debug", "Erreur pendant onEnabled +" + e.toString())
    }
}


override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

    Log.i("Debug", "Updating TodoWidget")

    try {
        appWidgetIds?.forEach { id ->

            // Met en place l'intent qui lance le service. Le service
            // Se chargera de fournir les données pour remplir la liste
            val intent = Intent(context, TodoWidgetService::class.java)

            // Fournit l'id du widget
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id)
            intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

            // Récupère le layout
            val layout = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.todowidget)

            // Applique l'adapter (via l'intent) sur la listview
            layout.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.Main_LV_Todotasks, intent)

            // Template permettant de gérer les listener sur les ITEMS
            // L'intent est créer vers TodoWidgetProvider puisque le Provider est AUSSI un Broadcast receiver
            val intentTemplate = Intent(context, TodoWidgetProvider::class.java)
            intentTemplate.action = StaticVariables.ACTION_DELETETASK
            layout.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.Main_LV_Todotasks,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentTemplate, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

            // Ajoute un clickListener sur le bouton le bouton
            val intentAddNew = Intent(context, javaClass)
            intentAddNew.action = ACTION_STARTACTIVITY_NEWTASK

            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Main_IBT_Add,
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context?.applicationContext, 0, intentAddNew, 0));

            // Applique le layout
            appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(id, layout)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Debug", "Error updating widget" + e.toString())
    }

}

/**
 * Méthode représentant l'implémentation de la classe BroadcastReceiver
 *
 * Permet de récupérer les intents correspondants aux actions de l'utilisateur
 * pour effectuer les traitements en conséquences
 */
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent)

    Log.i("Debug", "Provider received an intent")
    // Si le bouton d'ajout a été clické
    if (ACTION_STARTACTIVITY_NEWTASK.equals(intent?.action)) {

        // Démarrage de l'activité nouvelle task (qui simule une popup)
        val i = Intent(context, NewTaskActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        context?.startActivity(i)
    }

    // Si l'utilisateur à entré une nouvelle tâche
    if (ACTION_NEWTASK.equals(intent?.action)) {

        // Récupère les données
        var todoTitle = intent?.extras?.get(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_TITLE) as String?
        var todoContent = intent?.extras?.get(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_CONTENT) as String?
        var todoAlert = intent?.extras?.get(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_ALERT) as Long?

        // Lance l'ajout
        addNewTask(context!!, todoTitle, todoContent, todoAlert)
    }

    // Si l'utilisateur à supprimé une tâche
    if (ACTION_DELETETASK.equals(intent?.action)) {
        // Récupère les données
        var deletePosition = intent?.extras?.get(StaticVariables.EXTRA_DELETETODO_POSITION) as Int?

        if (deletePosition != null) {
            // Lance la suppression
            deleteTask(context!!, deletePosition)
        }
    }

    // Si le téléphone a été redémaré
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent?.getAction())) {

        // Récupére une liste des tâches enregistrées
        var currentTodoList: ArrayList<TodoTask> = ArrayList(Helper_SharedPreferences.GetTodoList(context!!, StaticVariables.SHARED_TODOLIST))
        var currentAlarmList = ArrayList<Date>()

        // Si il y avait des alarmes enregistrées
        if (currentTodoList?.size > 0) {

            // Parcours des alarmes
            currentTodoList.forEach { task ->

                if (task._alert != null) {

                    // Réajoute l'alarme
                    Helper_Alarm.createAlarm(context!!, task)
                    currentAlarmList.add(task._alert!!)
                }
            }
        }

        // Réenregistre la liste des alarmes
        Helper_SharedPreferences.SaveAlarmList(context, currentAlarmList, StaticVariables.SHARED_ALARMLIST)
    }

    // Si on reçoit un intent pour envoyer une notification
    if (ACTION_ALERT_TASK.equals(intent?.action)) {

        Log.i("Debug", "ALARM RECEIVED" + intent?.action)

        // Récupération de la Task sérializée
        val taskString = intent?.extras?.getString(StaticVariables.EXTRA_ALERT_TASK)

        // Désérialization
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context!!)

        val gson = Gson()
        val task: TodoTask = gson.fromJson(taskString, TodoTask::class.java)
        // Création du channel (API > 26)
        createNotificationChannel(context)

        // Création de la notification
        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, StaticVariables.NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
                .setContentTitle(task?._title)
                .setContentText(task?._content)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(task?._content))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        notificationManager.notify(5258, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

And here the issued activity (the code that send the broadcast in ok_ClickListener :

```
class NewTaskActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

// region Fields

// Déclaration des vues
internal lateinit var et_content: EditText
internal lateinit var et_title: EditText
internal lateinit var ll_parent: LinearLayout
internal lateinit var bt_ok: Button
internal lateinit var ibt_alert: ImageButton
internal lateinit var ll_alert: LinearLayout
internal lateinit var tv_alert: TextView

// Déclaration des valeurs demandées à l'utilisateur
internal var alert_date: Date? = null
internal var alert_year: Int = 0
internal var alert_month: Int = 0
internal var alert_day: Int = 0

// endregion

// region constructor

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_task)

    // Récupère l'editTexte du contenu
    et_content = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_ET_content)
    et_title = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_ET_title)
    ll_parent = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_LL_parent)
    bt_ok = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_BT_Ok)
    ibt_alert = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_IBT_alert)
    ll_alert = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_LL_alert)
    tv_alert = findViewById(R.id.NewTaskAct_TV_alert)

    // Ajoute l'évènement au click de ok
    bt_ok.setOnClickListener(ok_ClickListener)

    // Ajout l'évènement de création de l'alert (ouverture de la popup)
    ibt_alert.setOnClickListener(alert_ClickListener)
    ll_alert.setOnClickListener(alert_ClickListener)

    // Demande le focus pour afficher le clavier
    et_title?.requestFocus()


    // Ajoute les listeners de saisie
    et_title?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(string: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            if (string?.length!! >= 2) {
                bt_ok.isEnabled = true
            } else if (et_content?.length() < 2) {
                bt_ok.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    })

    et_content?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(string: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            if (string?.length!! >= 2) {
                bt_ok.isEnabled = true
            } else if (et_title?.length() < 2) {
                bt_ok.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    })
}

// endregion

// region Listeners

/**
 * TouchListener permettant l'ajout de la tâche
 */
val ok_ClickListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { it ->

    try {

        // Création de l'intent personnalisé pour renvoyer le résultat
        val i = Intent(StaticVariables.ACTION_NEWTASK)

        // Ajoute les données de la nouvelle tâche en extra
        i.putExtra(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_TITLE, et_title?.text?.toString()!!)
        i.putExtra(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_CONTENT, et_content?.text?.toString()!!)
        i.putExtra(StaticVariables.EXTRA_NEWTODO_ALERT, alert_date?.time)

        // Envoie l'intent pour que tous les receivers potentiels les reçoivent
        sendBroadcast(i)

        Log.i("Debug","Broadcast aparently sent.")
        // Ferme l'activité
        finish()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Debug", "Error during click ok button action.")
    }
}

/**
 * Cette méthode permet d'ouvrir les popups de sélection de date et heure
 */
val alert_ClickListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { it ->

    // Lance la sélection de la date
    showDatePicker()
}

/**
 * TouchListener permettant de fermer l'activité de nouvelle tâche
 */
val cancel_ClickListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { it ->

    // Termine l'activité
    finish()
}

// endregion

// region Helpers


/**
 * Permet de lancer la popup de sélection de la date (année mois jour)
 */
private fun showDatePicker() {

    // Récupère la date du jour
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    // Déclare la boite de dialog de sélection à partir de la date du jour
    val dialog = DatePickerDialog(this,

            // Action a éffectuer une fois la date sélectionnée
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, yearSelected, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

                // Affecte les
                alert_year = yearSelected
                alert_month = monthOfYear
                alert_day = dayOfMonth

                // Lance le picker de time
                showTimeicker()

            }, year, month, day)

    // Ouvre la dialog
    dialog.show()
}

/**
 * Permet de lancer la popup de sélection de la date (année mois jour)
 */
private fun showTimeicker() {

    // Récupère la date du jour
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
    val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    // Déclare la boite de dialog de sélection à partir de la date du jour
    val dialog = TimePickerDialog(this,

            // Action a éffectuer une fois la date sélectionnée
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hourSet, minuteSet ->

                // Créer une nouvelle date
                alert_date = Helper_Date.createDate(alert_year, alert_month, alert_day, hourSet, minuteSet)

                if (alert_date != null) {

                    // Récupère une chaîne pour l'affichage
                    val stringDate = Helper_Date.getStringDateCurrentCulture(this, alert_date!!)
                    tv_alert.setText(stringDate)
                }

            }, hour, minute, true)

    // Ouvre la dialog
    dialog.show()
}

// endregion

// region overrides

// endregion
```

}

I tried everything ... changing context with applicationContext included. I really don't know how to fix this I need your help :D .

According that the broadcast is received at the beginnning of the widget's lifecycle maybe the problem come from this ...

Thank you for your help,

Etienne ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally git it working by changing these lines :

`// Création de l'intent personnalisé pour renvoyer le résultat
        val i = Intent(StaticVariables.ACTION_NEWTASK)`

By these lines :

```
// Création de l'intent personnalisé pour renvoyer le résultat
val i = Intent(this, TodoWidgetProvider::class.java)
i.action = StaticVariables.ACTION_NEWTASK
```

I didn't really understood what was the problem ... But if it can help someone.